# Select different values in column from the same table ID in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have searched much about it but I couldn't find any related information about my problem. I have a dataset like this.

```
Column1    Column2
   A          B    
   A          B
   A          C
   X          B
   X          B
   Y          C
   Y          B
   T          A
   T          A
   T          A
```

I can distinct Column1 with total number of occurences. But I actually want to remove the constant rows. When I run the query, the result should be like this;

```
Column1    Column2
   A          B    
   A          B
   A          C
   Y          C
   Y          B
```

As we see above A and Y have different values in Column2. How do I query this? I am using `Sql Server 2014`

Comment: So you want to remove the rows where the value in column 1 only ever has one value in column 2? If they have multiple column 2 possibilities you want to leave them?

Comment: Yes. That is what exactly I want to query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to count the occurences of the pairings before you do anything

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, count(*)
FROM [source]
GROUP BY ColumnA, ColumnB
```

That will give you a list of each pairing and how often it occurs. Next you want to count how many pairings each value in ColumnA has, and cut out the ones with only one option:

```
SELECT ColumnA, count(*)
FROM
    (
    SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, count(*)
    FROM [source]
    GROUP BY ColumnA, ColumnB
    )
GROUP BY ColumnA
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

That will give you a list of ColumnA values that you're looking for. From there you want to look for those values of ColumnA in your original data with a `WHERE .. IN` statement:

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB
FROM [source]
WHERE ColumnA IN
    (
    SELECT ColumnA, count(*)
    FROM
        (
        SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, count(*)
        FROM [source]
        GROUP BY ColumnA, ColumnB
        )
    GROUP BY ColumnA
    HAVING count(*) > 1
    )
```

Comment: Thank you Fritz. With some configuration for sql server I could make it.

Answer (score 1):

COUNT(DISTINCT...) might work with a CTE:

```
; WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Column1
    FROM [my_table]
    GROUP BY Column1
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Column2) > 1
)
SELECT t.*
FROM [my_table] t
JOIN CTE ON CTE.Column1 = t.Column1;
```